# Search without inputting data will result to stock up of website

Tags: javascript, ajax

I encounter problem on on my search when i click search without inserting data  the website will stop.

```
$('#search-btn').on('click',function(){
    var query = $("#keyword").val();
    var query_url = "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/searchItem'); ?>";

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: query_url,
        data:{query: $("#keyword").val()},
        dataType:'json',
        async: false,
        success:function(d){

            $("#example tbody").html("");
            for(i in d){
                $("#example tbody").append("<tr><td style='text-align: center; color:' data-code='TRUE'>" + d[i]['item_code'] + "</td><td style='text-align: left' data-name='TRUE'>" + d[i]['item_name'] + "</td><td><div style='text-align: center'><input type='button' value='ADD' class='k-button' id='" + d[i]['item_code'] + "' data-item=TRUE /></div></td></tr>");
            }

        },

    });    

});
```

Comment: Do you want to search only if text entered in searchbox ?

Comment: @MahMoodRehman Yes sir  when the text box have data   and had click the submit button. the problem is the search without data  will cause to website crash

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#search-btn').on('click',function(){
var query = $("#keyword").val();
var query_url = "<?php echo site_url('item_controller/searchItem'); ?>";
if (query !== '') {
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: query_url,
    data:{query: $("#keyword").val()},
    dataType:'json',
    async: false,
    success:function(d){

        $("#example tbody").html("");
        for(i in d){
            $("#example tbody").append("<tr><td style='text-align: center; color:' data-code='TRUE'>" + d[i]['item_code'] + "</td><td style='text-align: left' data-name='TRUE'>" + d[i]['item_name'] + "</td><td><div style='text-align: center'><input type='button' value='ADD' class='k-button' id='" + d[i]['item_code'] + "' data-item=TRUE /></div></td></tr>");
        }

      },

   });   
 } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add if condition to your code.

```
    $('#search-btn').on('click',function(){
    var query = $("#keyword").val();
    if(query === '') { 
alert('please enter some text');}else{ //do your stuff }.
```

you can also use this condition for checking your string value .

```
if(query.length == 0) {
    }
```